# Separate words of the string and store them in stack in MIPS

Tags: string, split, mips

```
.data
      string: .asciiz "Please enter the string : "
      newLine: .asciiz "\n"
      buffer: .space 100
.text
.globl main

 main:
      la $a0, string
      li $v0, 4
      syscall
      
      li $v0, 8
      la $a0, buffer
      li $a1, 100
      syscall

      la $t0, buffer
      
      li $t0, 0
      subu $sp, $sp, 4
      li $v0, 4
      syscall
```

Here above is beginning of the my code. And I need to separate each words of the string and then store them in the stack. First I tried to store word in stack as allocation memory with stack pointer and it works now. But I need to store each word(not characters) of the sentence such as

> Hello I am Furkan

So for this example there should be 4 words in stack.

```
Hello
I
am
Furkan
```

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Work out what you want to store in C first: that will allow you to address issues of identifying words and representing them in storage.  (If the stack is confusing in C, then use an array of words as if it were the stack.)  Once it works in C you can translate that to assembly language.  If you're having trouble translating, you'll have the C code to point to for asking translation questions.

Comment: I have a code on C language but translating a bit difficult that's why I'm looking for an answer. Can you help me in this way ?

Comment: Show the particular C code that you're having difficulty translating, and ask a technical question about the difficulty of translating some particular C construct, rather than asking for a complete answer to your homework.

Comment: @FurkanOcalan There's some code here, but it's not really an attempt at solving the problem you're asking about. I second Erik's suggestion of simplifying the problem; just split the words and print them for starters. Then store them in an array. Then store them in a stack. Trying to do all of this in one fell swoop is overwhelming and hard to take action on. If splitting the words out is too hard, just loop over the string and print the chars -- you can always go one simpler. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).